# Как переверстать таблицу блоками?

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Хочу переделать главную страницу сайта. Сейчас вверху изображение, под ним таблица, ширина которой должна быть равна ширине этого изображения. Выставлять ширину таблицы в % дело абсолютно бессмысленное, т.к. на разных мониторах она будет разной ширины. Выставила ширину в пикселях, и тоже фигня получается. На небольшом мониторе верхнее изображение уменьшается и полностью влезает в экран. А правый край таблицы вылезает за пределы экрана. Слышала, что можно то же самое сверстать блоками, и тогда на маленьких экранах блоки будут выстраиваться друг под другом. В последний раз я верстала лет 10 назад, и про блочную верстку знаю только то, что она есть. Кто-нибудь может показать пример такой верстки, чтобы можно было сделать по аналогии?
Свидетельства моего позора прикладываю.

[image: Это макет]

[image: Это то, что получилось]

Comment: Почитай про `grid css` и про `flexbox`, они решают данную задачу. Тут на сайте есть подобные решения, поищи по данным запросам

Comment: Хочешь сделать это самостоятельно, чтобы научили тебя делать или сделали за тебя?

Comment: пиши мне в вк, см в профиле.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы сайт корректно отображался на экранах разных размеров после определения разметки указанным в комментарии способом можно использовать медиа-запросы:

```
@media (max-width: ...px){
CSS-стили
...
}
```